# Android get value from specific View in ListView

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a custom listView with several Views in it.
I am trying to get a value from a specific TextView attached to the ListView at argument x.

If I were to do this with by calling an OnClickListener I would simply grab the view with the following:

TextView example = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.example);

However I am trying to do this without the user clicking.

I want to find the value from the view contained within any/ all positions in the listview

Something along the lines of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount; i++) {

    TextView neededTextView = (TextView) listview.getPosition(i).findViewById(R.id.modelId);
    String textNeeded = neededTextView.getText();

    return textNeeded;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `String value = (String) adapter.getItem(i)`

Comment: Can you post your code of adapter  of your listview?